# Hibernate/JPA handling empty result set

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, null

I have a criteria builder which is defined as returning a Long. If the result set is empty, the whole application fails. How do I handle this to return a set number, e.g. 1000?

```
Long yesterday = new Long(0);

CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> q = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<CustomerHistory> hist = q.from(CustomerHistory.class);

q.multiselect(hist.get("total"));
Date yesterDate = new LocalDate().minusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate();

Predicate w1 = cb.equal(hist.<Date>get("date"), yesterDate);
Predicate w2 = cb.equal(hist.get("customer"), customer);
q.where(w1,w2);

yesterday = em.createQuery(q).getSingleResult();


return yesterday < tot;
```

Comment: Catch your exceptions, in this case you need to catch a `NoResultException` : http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html

Comment: Ah, it would make sense! I will learn one day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an empty resultset, the `Query.getSingleResult()` throws a `javax.persistence.NoResultException` which is a `RuntimeException`. You are free to catch it in a try-catch block and handle it from there.

To set the maximum amount of result set, call the `Query.setMaximumResults(int maxResult)` and call the `getResultList()` (which returns a `List` of the entity desired).

Answer (score 1):

From JPA API

```
java.lang.Object getSingleResult()
Execute a SELECT query that returns a single untyped result.
Returns:
   the result
Throws:
   NoResultException - if there is no result
   NonUniqueResultException - if more than one result
```

Consider catch the Exception of NoResultException and continue with the logic